# Copy of ngModel also gets affected

Tags: html, angular, angular-directive

I am trying to store all student details by this function.
Consider each student has `name` and an `array[]` named marks of numbers (For simplicity)

```
populate(){
    this.service.getAll()
    .subscribe(response=>{
      this.paginatedResponse = response
      this.students = this.paginatedResponse['result']
      this.studentsCopy = this.paginatedResponse['result']
    })
  }
```

Consider the total options to range from 1 to 10
So I am using a `multi-select dropdown` (custom component), and feed in the `ngModel` like this,
consider in TS I have made a dictionary kind of array with

```
 options=[{id:1,text:"one",..... till 10]
```

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let student of students;let i = index">
<custom-multiselect
  [items]="options"
  [(ngModel)]="students[i].marks"
  (ngModelChange)="onSelection(i)"
  optionsKey="text"
  optionsValue="id"
></custom-multiselect>
</ng-container>
```

And I have onSelection to output both this.students.marks, this.studentsCopy.marks

So Initially, let student 1 has name:"Adam", marks:[1,2,3]
The multiselect onload initially shows up 1,2,3 highlighted, since the ngModel binding is done, as I select mark:4 for him 
then for this.students.marks it shows, name:"Adam", marks:[1,2,3,4] which is totally acceptable,
But why is this.studentsCopy.marks also showing the same, ngModel is connected to the original data and not the copy right?

[EDIT]:
for this,

```
    console.log(this.routeCopy[index].roles)
    console.log(this.routeCopy[index].roles instanceof Array)
    this.routeCopy[index].roles = this.routeCopy[index].roles.push(333)
    console.log(this.routeCopy[index].roles)
```

I got 
(2) [2, 1]

[2] which wen opened says,
0:2
1:333

true
 2 -> not an array instead a number

So next time on select it says push is not a function as it got converted to a number? why did the array instance after pushing became a number?

Comment: Share it in stackbiltz, and after an question is answered, if you get another issue, you should ask a new question instead of editing existing question

Comment: But, there is a problem, to stackbiltz I cannot import in the custom-multiselect(cookedup name), as it is an internal UI component of the company I am working for, i.e it shouldn't be shared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
this.studentsCopy = [...this.students]
```

or,

```
this.studentsCopy = this.students.map(object => ({ ...object }))
```

The spread operator (`...`) can be used to initialize arrays and objects from another array or object without reference ( Deep Copying )

Comment: Try the modified answer

Comment: Thanks, it worked !
Will approve the answer after the minimum time for approval expires !

Comment: And how do we push a element to the copied one,
console.log(this.student[index].marks)
console.log(this.studentCopy[index].marks)
this.studentCopy[index].roles = this.routeCopy[index].marks.push(333)
console.log(this.studentCopy[index].marks)
It says push isnt a function,
The log returns like [1,2,3,4] [1,2,3] then error

Comment: Show the output of `console.log(this.studentCopy[index].marks) `

Comment: for this,
```console.log(this.routes[index].roles)
    console.log(this.routeCopy[index].roles)
    console.log(this.routeCopy[index].roles instanceof Array)
    this.routeCopy[index].roles = this.routeCopy[index].roles.push(222)
    console.log(this.routeCopy[index].roles)
```

I got 
(2) [2, 1]


[2] which wen opened says,
0:2
1:333


true
2 -> not an array instead a number

So next type on select it says push is not a function as it got converted to a number

Comment: May be there is a probkem wuth your json data, as the error clearly says that `this.studentCopy[index].marks` isn't an array, therefore caanot perform `push` operation

Comment: it pushes data for the first time, instance is array,
But later after pushing it changes the array to a number

Comment: push operation returns a number, 
so instead of myarr = myarr.push(5) do just myarr.push(5) and not to reassign

Answer (score 0):

This is you reference issue, you can solved this using lodash

```
this.studentsCopy = _.cloneDeep(this.paginatedResponse['result']);
```